# How to Connect SAP BW DataSource to IBM Cognos Analytics

Tags: connection, datasource, cognos, sap-bw

I am trying to set up a SAP BW DataSource in my IBM Cognos Analytics Environment. First of all what I did was:

- installed IBM Cognos Analytics via EASY INSTALL
- configured the Cognos Analytics Environment via IBM Cognos Configuration
- installed SAP GUI 7.50
- set up the DataSource Connection to my SAP BW System

If I test the Connection, I get the following Error:

> ```
> For dynamic query mode: Handler-Traceback:
> [the_dispatcher] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.performance.PerformanceIndicationHandler
> [the_dispatcher] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler
> [service_lookup] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.engine.ServiceLookupHandler
> [load_balancer] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler
> [wrapped_lb_forwarder] com.cognos.pogo.auth.NewAuthHandler
> [lb_forwarder] com.cognos.p2plb.clerver.LoadBalanceHandler
> [queryChainHandler] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler
> [queryAsyncHandler] com.cognos.pogo.async.impl.AsyncHandler
> [queryServiceHandler] com.cognos.xqebifw.cubingservices.CubingServicesHandler
> ```
>
> [image]

Can anybody help me solve this Problem? Do I need to prepare the SAP System, or do I have to set up any RFC connection?

Also the configuration of the SAP BW namespace ends up in an error:

> ```
> ['SAP BW Admin']
> [ FEHLER ] AAA-LPS-0005 Keine Kommunikation mit Vorgänger-Namespace-Server
> möglich. Er ist möglicherweise nicht mehr verfügbar. Versuchen Sie es später erneut.
> [ FEHLER ] java.io.IOException: Failed to send HTTP request or read HTTP response
> [ FEHLER ] java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>
> ['SAP BW Admin']
> [ FEHLER ] AAA-AUT-0013 Der Benutzer ist bereits in allen verfügbaren Namespaces
> authentifiziert.
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to embed the images of your error messages to make your question more easily readable. However, please add your exception messages etc. as text and not as images. [Look here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) for more information why you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

COGNOS BI should fully work with SAP BW.

Setting up the Namespace for SAP BW is in my eyes a bit strange. You should consider not to do it.

For Setting up a datasource for COGNOS ANALYTICS you Need the 64 bit RFC from SAP. A SAP GUI Installation won't help alone.